# java regex quiz

Tags: java, regex

It is really hard to understand regex world.

Can anybody explain the way of the regex makes the result like,

if n is 1, result will be 23020, n is 2 -> 33, n is 3 -> 2103, 4 -> 32

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "some023020 num ber 033 02103 32 meh peh beh 4328";
}

    static String nthNumber(String s, int n) {
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        "\\D*(?:\\d+\\D+){" + (n-1) + "}0*(\\d+).*");

      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
      matcher.matches();
      return matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Comment: Regex is equivelent to [Finite State Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_automaton). You have to understand _FSA_ first.

Comment: This is a really weird quiz because it seems like all cases can be trivially implemented with something like ... “^[.]*(23023)[.]*$” and so on for n=2,3,4. Didn’t test regex but you get the idea

Comment: After pasting the regex into http://regex101.com what exactly don’t you understand?

Answer (score 1):

Consider n = 1. Then your pattern becomes :

```
\D*(?:\d+\D+){0}0*(\d+).*
```

First, you need to understand what the group numbers denote in `matcher.group()`. Group 0 contains the sub-string that matches the *complete pattern*.

**In your case this is the whole string. Why?**

`\D*` - matches zero or more of [^0-9] i.e all characters except 0-9. So it will match the first 4 letters **"some"**.

`(?:\d+\D+){0}` - Match one or more of [0-9] and one or more of [^0-9]. The `?:` at the beginning is called the `non capturing group`. It basically means don't consider it as a group. The {0} indicates **how many times** `(?:\d+\D+){0}` should be matched. Right now it is 0, so match nothing.

`0*` - Match one or more 0. So this matches with the **"0"** after **"some"**. So we have matched **some0** up until now.

`(\d+)` - Match one or more of [0-9]. This matches **"23020"**. Observe how \d+ is inside the `()` and it doesn't have `?:` at the beginning. Which means this will be our group 1. (and that is why matcher.group(1) for n=1 return 23020).

`.*` - Match zero or more of any character. So this matches till the end of the string.

So this is why group 0 contains the complete string.

**Now moving to group 1.**

Group 1 in our case is `(\d+)` - sub-string containing one or more of [0-9]. But this is not it. **The part of the string that precedes this sub-string should also match the pattern `\D*(?:\d+\D+){0}0*`. This is very important.**

So let's quickly analyze your string.

`\D*` - matches **"some"**

`(?:\d+\D+){0}` - Match zero occurences (because of {0}). So matches nothing.

`0*` - matches **"0"**. So we have matched **"some0"**.

`(\d+)` - matches **23020**.

This answers the first part of your question : When n=1, why result is **23020**?

**Before we move ahead, note that space is also a character which is matched by \D. This sounds trivial but is often overlooked.**

Now when n=2, your pattern becomes:

`\D*(?:\d+\D+){1}0*(\d+).*`

Let's quickly analyze it:

`\D*` - matches **"some"**

`(?:\d+\D+){1}` - This time, we need to match exactly one occurence of `(?:\d+\D+)`. So this would be **"023020 num ber "**

`0*` - matches the 0. So we have matched upto **"some023020 num ber 0"**

(\d+) - matches **33** (and not **33 02103 32** because of the space).

So, when n=2, matcher.group(1) return 33.

You can analyze n=3,4 in the same way.

Hope this helps! The best thing to do when you are lost (not necessarily in regex) is to look at the official documentation. Read it completely, not just brushing over the cheat sheet. This way you get a better understanding.